# generic functions of S3 class

Tags: r

According to Robert Gentleman the general form of a generic function, as seen in the example below, is for a single expression, which is the call to UseMethod, which is the mechanism that helps to dispatch to the appropriate method. An example of a generic function is mean.

```
mean
#function (x, ...)
#UseMethod("mean")
#<environment: namespace:base>
```

in R 4.0 i get

```
mean
#standardGeneric for "mean" defined from package "base"
#function (x, ...) 
#standardGeneric("mean")
#<environment: 0x561858277bb8>
#Methods may be defined for arguments: x
#Use  showMethods("mean")  for currently available ones.
```

Why the ouputs are different and  what should be understood from the differences?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.4.2
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.2

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] BSgenome_1.56.0      rtracklayer_1.48.0   Biostrings_2.56.0   
 [4] XVector_0.30.0       GenomicRanges_1.42.0 GenomeInfoDb_1.26.7 
 [7] IRanges_2.24.1       S4Vectors_0.28.1     BiocGenerics_0.36.1 
[10] BiocManager_1.30.12 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13             zlibbioc_1.36.0            
 [3] GenomicAlignments_1.24.0    BiocParallel_1.24.1        
 [5] lattice_0.20-44             tools_4.0.0                
 [7] grid_4.0.0                  SummarizedExperiment_1.20.0
 [9] Biobase_2.50.0              matrixStats_0.58.0         
[11] crayon_1.4.1                Matrix_1.3-3               
[13] GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.4      bitops_1.0-7               
[15] RCurl_1.98-1.3              DelayedArray_0.16.3        
[17] compiler_4.0.0              MatrixGenerics_1.2.1       
[19] Rsamtools_2.4.0             XML_3.99-0.6
```

Comment: I get something along the lines of the first one (but with a bytecode) in 4.0.0 on Windows, so it might be helpful to have the output of  `sessionInfo()` for your system.

Comment: standardGeneric is S4, not S3.

Comment: @Miff. Thank you. I just did added the sessionInfo().

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. Thank you for pointing that out . The author of the book R 4 bioinformatics used mean as generic function /dispatching mechanism that illustrates  how lax is the S3 class system. Do you mind please explaining why  i am getting an S4 related output though?

Comment: That is just how it is written. Maybe it was changed from S3 to S4 since the source you are using was written.

Comment: My suspicion is that this could be to do with BiocGenerics which does a lot of stuff with S4. Maybe try starting R with the option `--vanilla` to see if you get the same behaviour without the loaded packages.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck .Thank you!

Comment: @Miff. Thank you!